# Makefile ifneq condition fails

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am adding some conditional flag which depends upon the gcc version
Below if the makefile snippet

```
CPPFLAGS :=  -O0  -g
CXXFLAGS := -fPIC
GCCVERSION = $(shell gcc --version | grep ^gcc |cut -b11-16)
ifneq ($(GCCVERSION),"4.1.2")
CPPFLAGS +=  -std=c++0x
CXXFLAGS += -m64
endif
```

The ifneq condition fails. I have checked that my $(GCCVERSION)=4.1.2 as expected.

EDIT:
I have already tried below options
    ifneq ($(GCCVERSION),4.1.2)
    ifneq ($(GCCVERSION),'4.1.2')
    ifneq ("$(GCCVERSION)","4.1.2")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip `$(GCCVERSION)`:

```
CPPFLAGS :=  -O0  -g
CXXFLAGS := -fPIC
GCCVERSION = $(shell gcc --version | grep ^gcc |cut -b11-16)
ifneq ($(strip $(GCCVERSION)),4.1.2)
CPPFLAGS +=  -std=c++0x
CXXFLAGS += -m64
endif
```

Comment: That is, OP has probably a trailing whitespace in `GCCVERSION`.

Comment: Worked, thanks. But without strip also my value was exactly 4.1.2 .Then what does strip do more ?

Comment: ah, yes, I had a whitespace. Sorry my bad.

Comment: @Ajit check your definition of `GCCVERSION`, you probably have a trailing whitespace in it.